# Short story from maybe 20-30 years ago about astronauts trapped in a ship by a guardian robot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As far as I remember, a couple of astronauts were visiting (repairing?) a satellite or some sort of space ship. There was a security system to deter intruders, maybe a robot, but it went haywire and just tried to kill the astronauts.

They were trapped unless they could find a way to outwit the guardian system. I cannot remember how they did it but I'd love to read this again, if the title or collection it appears in could be identified?

Comment: Do you remember anything about how they outsmart the robot? Logic bomb? Shining a flashlight on its sensors? High explosives?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall where you read this?  Was it in a magazine or an anthology?  Do you recall any associated art (cover art or interior art)?

Comment: Thank you both. Unfortunately all I can remember is that it was in a paperback of short stories. It was so long ago I cannot recall anything about the cover or name. Also I have no idea how they defeated the robot/guardian, I think they were unable to move or not move far/quick as the robot sensed their motion.

Comment: Reminds me of Life Hutch by Harlan Ellison.

Comment: Thanx Shawn, I think you've nailed it!

Comment: same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132582/short-story-about-a-space-pilot-trapped-in-a-hab-by-a-robot